# Do Assistive Text, Error Message, Character Counter exist for Jetpack Compose TextField?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

In material design [TextField page](https://material.io/components/text-fields#anatomy) `TextField` has properties such as

[image]

> Assistive elements provide additional detail about text entered into
> text fields.
>
> 1. Helper text Helper text conveys additional guidance about the input field, such as how it will be used. It should only take up a single
>    line, being persistently visible or visible only on focus.
> 2. Error message When text input isn't accepted, an error message can display instructions on how to fix it. Error messages are displayed
>    below the input line, replacing helper text until fixed.
> 3. Icons Icons can be used to message alerts as well. Pair them with error messages to provide redundant alerts, which are useful when you
>    need to design for colorblind users.
> 4. Character counter Character or word counters should be used if there is a character or word limit. They display the ratio of
>    characters used and the total character limit.

Do these properties exist for `Jetpack Compose TextField` as of `compose 1.0.0-alpha09`?

Comment: According to the issue tracker it looks like this one is in-flight.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182142737

Comment: The above issue has been resolved as of beta06, however it does not introduce any of the OP's missing properties.

Comment: according to this change (https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1651127/9/compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/TextFieldImpl.kt#139), just add `isError` prop to your text field. Yet, no idea how word/char counter implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With **M3** you can use the the **`supportingText`** attribute that is the optional supporting text to be displayed below the text field.

For **characters count** you have to applied `textAlign = TextAlign.End`:

```
val maxChar = 5

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.length <= maxChar) text = it
    },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    supportingText = {
        Text(
            text = "${text.length} / $maxChar",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
        )
    },
)
```

[image]

The same attribute can be used for **helper text** and **message errors**:

```
val errorMessage = "Text input too long"
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
var isError by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
val charLimit = 10

fun validate(text: String) {
    isError = text.length > charLimit
}

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
        validate(text)
    },
    singleLine = true,
    isError = isError,
    supportingText = {
        if (isError) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                text = "Limit: ${text.length}/$charLimit",
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
            )
        }
    },
    trailingIcon = {
        if (isError)
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Error,"error", tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error)
     }
)
```

[image]

---

With `M2` there aren't built-in properties to display an error message or the counter text.
However you can use a custom composable.

For the **error message** you can use something like:

```
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
var isError by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

fun validate(text: String) {
    isError = /* .... */
}

Column {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
            isError = false
        },
        trailingIcon = {
            if (isError)
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Error,"error", tint = MaterialTheme.colors.error)
        },
        singleLine = true,
        isError = isError,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions { validate(text) },
    )
    if (isError) {
        Text(
            text = "Error message",
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

To display the **counter text** you can use something like:

```
val maxChar = 5
Column(){
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.length <= maxChar) text = it
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
    Text(
        text = "${text.length} / $maxChar",
        textAlign = TextAlign.End,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(end = 16.dp)
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Jeez. Bring back the XML View rendering! All of this to display an error message on a Textfield

Comment: problem with those standalone views is that they get obscured by the keyboard. :/
only the textfield is kept above the keyboard

Answer (score 1):

`trailingIcon` for the icon.

For the text at the bottom I just used

```
Text(
    text = "Error message",
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp)
)
```

Might be included in the future? Weirdly enough the documentation for `isError` says:

> indicates if the text field's current value is in error. If set to
> true, the label, **bottom indicator** and trailing icon by default will
> be displayed in error color

What bottom indicator? There is no such thing. Weird.

Comment: Bottom indicator is the line under the text field, it gets red as well if `isError` is set.